# How to set up routing tables in EC2, so that ping works

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, firewall, ping, amazon-vpc

I have a wide open security group which I rely on for instances to be able to connect.  I also have a private network of 172.*. addresses, as shown here:

[image]

What do I need to do in order to allow servers launched with the same subnet id to talk to one another?  Currently, they can ssh to each other, but they cannot ping - even though I have opened up all firewall rules.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ping uses the ICMP protocol, not TCP.

[image: ICMP]

Routing tables are not involved in intra-subnet communication, unless you meant security groups.